# Convert excel date code (text style) in R program

Tags: r, excel, date, format

The question is quite simple: I have a txt data imported in R. However, I forgot to change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy. For example: instead of having 30/09/2015 I have 42277.

Of course I could go back to my excel and change the column format from number to date and get the dd/mm/yyyy format easily. But I was thinking if there is a way of doing that inside R. I have several packages here, such as XLConnect but there is nothing there.

Comment: What does 42277 represent? Days since 1900?

Comment: You have two choices: `class(DF$Date)="Date"` or `DF$Date=as.Date(DF$Date,origin="1970-01-01")` That solves your problem.

Comment: @Duck Not really... `as.Date(42277, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2085-10-01"`

Comment: Yes, sorry the correct option is `as.Date(42277, origin="1899-12-30") `

Comment: That will work @SeñorO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to convert Excel-style dates:

`as.Date(42277, origin="1899-12-30")`

Comment: Brilliant. Did you come up with that all by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The help file for `as.Date` discusses the vagaries of conversion from other time systems and includes a discussion and example for Excel.

```
 ## Excel is said to use 1900-01-01 as day 1 (Windows default) or
 ## 1904-01-01 as day 0 (Mac default), but this is complicated by Excel
 ## incorrectly treating 1900 as a leap year.
 ## So for dates (post-1901) from Windows Excel
 as.Date(35981, origin = "1899-12-30") # 1998-07-05
 ## and Mac Excel
 as.Date(34519, origin = "1904-01-01") # 1998-07-05
 ## (these values come from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214330)
```